# UIPickerView delegates not working

Tags: uipickerview, swift2

I have a Swift 2 SingleView app. This is the only scene in the app.

I've added two picker views to a single scene.  The picker view delegate and datasource protocols have been added.  I've created IBOutlets to each pickerview.  The two delegate and two datasource functions are there.

When I run the app, none of the datasource or delegate functions breakpoints I've added are hit.

Is there any piece I might be missing?

Comment: Post some code. My first suspicion though is that you didn't assign your delegate and datasource to the UIPicker's delegate and datasource properties.

Comment: @ScottH: That was the issue.  Thanks.  What I'm seeing is that it only spins through the first pickerview and doesn't have anything to do with the second.  I have both datasource and delegate connected to each pickerview.  Do you have some idea on that?

Comment: Not without seeing your code, I don't. Sorry.

Comment: @ScottH: Can you post your answer?  Otherwise, I'm doing to delete the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you are missing is wiring up your `delegate` and `dataSource` to the `UIPickerView` via

```
pickerView1.delegate = yourDelegate
pickerView1.dataSource = yourDataSource

pickerView2.delegate = yourDelegate
pickerView2.dataSource = yourDataSource
```